# Failed to load resource the server responded with status of (422 Unprocessable Entity) in FastApi and React.js

Tags: reactjs, axios, fastapi

I'm learning and following a [Deep leaning tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watchv=uldlsT98Bbs&list=PLeo1K3hjS3ut49PskOfLnE6WUoOp_2lsD&index=5) that uses FastApi to serve prediction models to a Reactjs App.

When i use Insomnia/postman, requests are returned but when i request for a prediction to my backend from the react app.

It returns a console log error: (422 Unprocessable Entity)and when i open the error it says {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"} referring to the predict method from http://localhost:8000/predict in the backend

my Api runs: "http://localhost:8000"  my frontend runs:    "http://localhost:3000"

Here is the Api code with **predict method** and [GitHub link](https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/Detecting-Potato-Blight-Using-CNN/blob/main/Api/main.py)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn 
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
 
app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost", 
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"], 
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("../saved-models/3")
CLASS_NAMES = ["Early Blight", "Late Blight", "Healthy"]

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "hello, I am alive"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))     
    return image

@app.post("/predict")                        #Here is the prediction method
async def predict(fil: UploadFile = File(...)):
    image = read_file_as_image(await fil.read())
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)             
    predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)           
    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
    confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
    return {
        'class': predicted_class,
        'confidence': float(confidence)
    }
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

Here is the react code to make the API request [link](https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/Detecting-Potato-Blight-Using-CNN/blob/main/frontend/src/home.js):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import React from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import { Paper, CardActionArea, CardMedia, Grid, TableContainer, Table, TableBody, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, Button, CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";
import cblogo from "./cblogo.PNG";
import image from "./bg.png";
import { DropzoneArea } from 'material-ui-dropzone';
import { common } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';


export const ImageUpload = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [image, setImage] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(false);
  let confidence = 0;

  const sendFile = async () => {
    if (image) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", selectedFile);
        let res = await axios({                         #here make the API request
        method: "post",
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
        data: formData,
      });
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setData(res.data);
      }
      setIsloading(false);
    }
  }
```

I have a .env file that reflects the REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000/predict url in the reactapp.

[image: click see the image of the .env file]

Comment: Your question title indicates a different error than the one you have in your actual question, but the error in your question is caused by your backend (FastAPI) expecting a POST operation, while your frontend code (React) sends a GET request. Your log shows that you do both POST and GET requests, so the code you've included might be the correct code - while you have a broken request somewhere else.

Comment: thanks MatsLindh, sorry about the confusion in the error, the console log error is as the question above [ 422: Unprocessable Entity ] but when i click on the error, it displays {"detail":"Method Not Allowed"}. And about Get request in the front end, where is it, i only see the method: "post" when making the API request to the backend !!

Comment: That's impossible for us to say without having access to your code, but since the request _also_ is for `/favicon.ico`, it's certainly coming from your browser. Are you reloading the app with `/predict` in the location bar and are serving the app from the same host as your FastAPI? Is it a different browser (since it uses ::1 which is ipv6, while your other requests are arriving on 127.0.0.1 - which is ipv4).?

Comment: @MatsLindh here is the code to the [backend Api Github](https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/Detecting-Potato-Blight-Using-CNN/blob/main/Api/main.py) and the [React Frontend Github](https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/Detecting-Potato-Blight-Using-CNN/blob/main/frontend/src/home.js).  About how am reloading the App, i am running  the backend Api using python and the frontend using react(npm start). So i run both servers from VScode then test the API calls using postman and they work but when use the Chrome browser to make Api calls i don't get any response, it loads endlessly.

Comment: So when i try using chrome js debugging tools. That's how i see the processable entity error. I thought given that the servers are running on different ports Api - http://localhost:8000 and the front end on http://localhost:3000,  things should work fine!!!

Comment: I'd love to hear what you did to get it working. I'm experiencing the exact same issues with an application I build using FastAPI (that works perfectly in e.g. Postman), but sending a POST request from by React frontend fails all the time, giving me the same 422 error as you had.